# How to define response headers for unary rpc

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc, protoc

In Go, I want to set some response headers from inside my rpc handler implementation. Specifically, I want to set some headers related to cache control.

However, when the rpc is defined as unary response, the method signature generated by protoc only includes the request context and request message. This is in contrast to the code generated from a streaming response, which includes the request message and a `grpc.ServerStream`.

Here's an example interface generated by protoc:

```
type CmsServer interface {
  GetPost(context.Context, *PostRequest) (*Post, error)
  GetPosts(*GetPostsOptions, Cms_GetPostsServer) error
}
```

In the example, `GetPosts` includes `Cms_GetPostsServer` parameter which is a `grpc.ServerStream` that appears to include methods to set custom response headers https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc#ServerStream (i have not tried this yet so correct me if this is wrong).

Meanwhile, `GetPost` doesn't appear to have any way to set response headers just by looking at the method signature (context.Context is only the request context, not the response context). So how do i set custom response headers for a unary response?

Comment: Are you sure that's the exact interface? All the methods usually have a variadic set of `CallOptions` at the end (`opts ...grpc.CallOption`).

Comment: @JimB I do see `(opts ...grpc.CallOption)` on the client methods, but not on the server methods

Comment: Oh yes, sorry -- I had that backwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Sending and receiving metadata - server side](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/Documentation/grpc-metadata.md#sending-and-receiving-metadata---server-side)

The request Context has the information to match the request with the connection. You use the [`grpc.SetHeader`](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc#SetHeader) or [`grpc.SendHeader`](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc#SendHeader) to write extra metadata from the server

```
func (s *server) SomeRPC(ctx context.Context, in *pb.someRequest) (*pb.someResponse, error) {
    // create and send header
    header := metadata.Pairs("header-key", "val")
    grpc.SendHeader(ctx, header)
    // create and set trailer
    trailer := metadata.Pairs("trailer-key", "val")
    grpc.SetTrailer(ctx, trailer)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! that makes perfect sense. from the source code of `grpc.SetHeader` i can see there is still a stream connection but it is "secretly" attached to context