# Set GRPC Header Response GO

Tags: go, http-headers, grpc, response-headers

I'm using grpc in golang and want to make my header like this

[image: Header]

I already tried 2 methode. First, i'm using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48631477/how-to-define-response-headers-for-unary-rpc) and it works, but the header is adding grpc-metadata- to it's key like this
[image: result]

My question is how to remove that word? and how to generate some values like date,content-length, cache-control etc, do i have to hardcoded it in my code like this?

```
header := metadata.New(map[string]string{"Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With,content-type, Accept,Authorization", "Server": "val2"})
grpc.SendHeader(ctx, header)
```

And the other methode is i'm using http.Responsewritter. this is my code like:

main.go

```
var (
    config *envcfg.Envcfg
    logger *logrus.Logger
    https http.ResponseWriter
)
func main() {
    
--------------------

    g.Go(func() error { return NewGRPCServer(config, logger, https) })
-------------------

}

func NewGRPCServer(config *envcfg.Envcfg, logger *logrus.Logger, https http.ResponseWriter) error {
    // create service handlers each grpc service server
    signupSvc, err := signup.New(config, logger, https)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
-----------------------------
    // register grpc service server
    grpcServer := grpc.NewServer()

    supb.RegisterSignServer(grpcServer, signupSvc)

    -------------------------------------------------------
}
```

api.go :

```
type Server struct {
    config ConfigStore
    logger Logger
    https http.ResponseWriter
}

func New(config ConfigStore, logger Logger, https http.ResponseWriter) (*Server, error) {
    return &Server{
        config: config,
        logger: logger,
        https: https,
    }, nil
}
```

function.go:

```
func (s *Server) SplashScreen(ctx context.Context,req *supb.RetrieveRequest, w http.ResponseWriter) (*supb.RetrieveResponse,error){
// do something
}
```

The problem is in main it said that signupSVC doesn't implement signServer like this:

```
Cannot use 'signupSvc' (type *Server) as type SignServer Type does not implement 'SignServer' need method: SplashScreen(context.Context, *RetrieveRequest) (*RetrieveResponse, error) have method: SplashScreen(ctx context.Context, req *supb.RetrieveRequest, w http.ResponseWriter) (*supb.RetrieveResponse, error)
```

where to place the http.Responsewriter ?